# Get the row data of current button pressed in Django Grid Pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-views

I have build Gridview pagination in django, where each row contains some record and a button to check status. I want to get back the current row data of button pressed..

Note that also, some row data contains the same id, so i cannot associated the id with button, here is the uniqe key for each row is **log_id**. I need to get back the log_id and email of the row whose button is pressed.

Here is my code...

```
  <div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if contacts.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ contacts.number }} of {{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if contacts.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>    
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
 <div class="table-responsive">    
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
 <!-- Columns Headings -->                  
<thead>
<th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
<th style="text-align:center;">Msg. ID</th>
<th style="text-align:center;">Sent To</th>
<th style="text-align:center;">Sent On</th>
<th style="text-align:center;">Status</th>
<th style="text-align:center;">Log Key</th>
<th style="text-align:center;">Check</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <div id="content">
    <form action="/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
{% for contact in contacts %}  
        {# Each "contact" is a Contact model object. #}
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><a style="color:Blue; text-decoration:none;" href="/messages/get/{{Message_ID }}/">{{ contact.Message_ID }}</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">{{ contact.email }}</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">{{ contact.Sent_On }}</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">{{ contact.Status }}</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">{{ contact.log_id }}</td>

    <td style="text-align:center;"><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Update"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-title="Edit" name="_check" value="{{ contact.log_id }}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span></button></p></td>

    </tr>
{% endfor %}   
        </div>
    </tbody>

</table>
    </form>  

  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? The value returned in the `_check` field will be the log_id, from which you can get the email, surely?

Comment: it is not returning, i write the follwing code but it is not printing on console, `if request.method == 'POST':`
        `if '_check' in request.POST:`
            `#user_id = request.contact.log_id`
           ` #print user_id``